# Proof that a set of inequalities is possible

Tags: inequality

I have the following set of inequalities, and need to know if there is a possible solution to them. It is acceptable to provide a numerical example that proves a possibility, or some proof that shows that they are impossible.

$ P_1>P_2>P_3>0 $

$ E_2>E_1>0 $

$ P_3E_2>P_2E_2-P_1E_1>0 $

Comment: The condition is written a bit different $P_1E_1>(P_2-P_3)E_2>0$. So  it's easier to choose values.

Comment: @user90369 Thanks, I'd be happy if you could show the steps taken to get to the condition

Comment: You can add $P_1E_1$ and substract $P_3E_2$. Nothing special but it's easier to choose values to get a valid inequality. You can continue: Divide with $P_1$ and $E_2$. On the one side $P$s, on the other side $E$s.

Comment: @user90369 doing your steps would yield $P_1E_1>(P_2-P_3)E_2>P_1E_1-P_3E_2$

Comment: Yes that's right. I forgot that $P_1E_1-P_3E_2$ is always positiv. But then we have $\frac{P_2-P_3}{P_1}<\frac{E_1}{E_2}<\frac{P_2}{P_1}$.

Comment: @user90369 $P_1E_1−P_3E_2$ is not guaranteed to be positive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45310/discussion-between-eyal-k-and-user90369).

Comment: The left side leads to $\frac{E_1}{E_2}>\frac{P_2-P_3}{P_1}$. The right side leads to $\frac{E_1}{E_2}<\frac{P_2}{P_1}$. E.g.: $(P_1,P_2,P_3):=(5,3,2)$ => $\frac{1}{5}<\frac{E_1}{E_2}<\frac{2}{5}$ => e.g. $\frac{E_1}{E_2}=\frac{3}{10}$ so e.g. $(E_1,E_2):=(3,10)$.

Comment: Chat is not possible, I am at my working place where this is blocked. But I think we have all conditions. I've written a short answer below.

Comment: I have added a comment below and a note in my anwer how to extend the value range of $\frac{E_1}{E_2}\in (0;1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take:

$$
P_1 = 3 , P_2 = 2, P_3 = 1, E_1 = 1 , E_2 = 2
$$

Then, $P_3E_2 = 2$, $P_2E_2 - P_1E_1 = 4-3= 1$ and $2>1>0$.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is $$0<\frac{P_2-P_3}{P_1}<\frac{E_1}{E_2}<\frac{P_2}{P_1}<1$$ as in the comments above explained:

To the third line of inequalities we add to the left inequality $P_1E_1-P_3E_2$ and to the right inequality only $P_1E_1$. Then we distinguish between the $E$-s and $P$-s.

The solution above contains all inequalities.

*Note*:

With $\displaystyle (P_1,P_2,P_3):=(n+1,n,n-1)$ one gets $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{E_1}{E_2}<\frac{n}{n+1}$.

With increasing $n$ one gets an increasing value range for $\displaystyle \frac{E_1}{E_2}$ in $(0;1)$.

Comment: It is a nice way to rearrange the third line, but it doesn't take into account the rest of the inequalities. For example $0<E_1/E_2<1$

Comment: If $0<\frac{E_1}{E_2}<\frac{P_2-P_3}{P_1}$ or $\frac{P_2}{P_1}<\frac{E_1}{E_2}<1$ then there is no solution. Or do you mean something else ?

Comment: I just meant that the line that I wrote is also one of the conditions, as well as the relations between the P values. I would like to be able to know what the range of solutions is

Comment: What I have understood is that the three lines should be valid together. And my answer is: This only works with the new double inequality, where the $E$-s and $P$-s are distinguished. You can choose first the $P$-s and find $E$-s or reversed or mixed. It's a method to find values (I have written an example in one of the last comments). The full condition: $0<\frac{P_2-P_3}{P_1}<\frac{E_1}{E_2}<\frac{P_2}{P_1}<1$ All your conditions are included.